# ORA-01722: invalid number on subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi i'm trying to execute my query and unfortunately trows me wih error of ORA-01722: invalid number

```
SELECT L.NEVENTLOGIDN, LPAD (nuserid, 6, '0') nuserid, u.susername, 
  TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + ( (ndatetime) / (60 * 60 * 24)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
  date_time, l.nreaderidn, r.sname, 
  CASE WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT GETREADERSBYFUNC('OUT', 'LOCKER') devices FROM dual ) THEN 'O' 
  WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT GETREADERSBYFUNC('IN', 'LOCKER') devices FROM dual ) THEN 'I' END logtype 
  FROM TB_EVENT_LOG l, TB_READER r, TB_USER u 
  WHERE 
  l.nreaderidn IN ( SELECT GETREADERSBYDESC('LOCKER') devices FROM dual) 
  AND NDATETIME >= ((TO_DATE ('2020-01-27' || ' 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
  AND ndatetime <= ((TO_DATE ('2020-01-28' || ' 12:00:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
  AND l.nuserid = u.suserid 
  AND l.nreaderidn = r.nreaderidn 
  ORDER BY 2, 4
```

I think the reason of error is this below.

1

```
CASE WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT GETREADERSBYFUNC('OUT', 'LOCKER') devices FROM dual ) THEN 'O'
```

sample data of GetReaderbyfunc

```
'544381428','544381436','544381433','544381424','544381043'
```

2

```
  WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT GETREADERSBYFUNC('IN', 'LOCKER') devices FROM dual ) THEN 'I' END logtype
```

3

```
WHERE 
  l.nreaderidn IN ( SELECT GETREADERSBYDESC('LOCKER') devices FROM dual) 


SELECT GETREADERSBYFUNC('OUT', 'LOCKER') devices FROM dual
```

result is below

```
'544381428','544381436','544381433','544381424','544381043'
```

because the nreaderidn  is a number type but when i put the result of it like bellow it is working

```
SELECT GETREADERSBYDESC('LOCKER') devices FROM dual
```

result is bellow

```
'544381050','544381441','544381428','544381436','544381431','544381064','544381433','544381435','544381424','544381043'



WHERE 
  l.nreaderidn IN ( '544381428','544381436','544381433','544381424','544381043')
```

functions

```
getreadersbyfunc (p_func VARCHAR2, p_desc VARCHAR2)
 RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   retVal VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN

   for cur_rec in (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = p_desc and upper(sname) like '%' || upper(p_func) || '%') 
   loop
        if retVal is NULL then
            retVal := '''' || cur_rec.nreaderidn || '''';
        else
            retVal := retVal || ',''' || cur_rec.nreaderidn || '''';
        end if;
   end loop;

   return retVal;


   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
       RAISE;


getreadersbydesc (p_description VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   retVal VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN

   for cur_rec in (SELECT nreaderidn FROM tb_reader where sdescription = p_description) 
   loop
        if retVal is NULL then
            retVal := '''' || cur_rec.nreaderidn || '''';
        else
            retVal := retVal || ',''' || cur_rec.nreaderidn || '''';
        end if;
   end loop;

   return retVal;


   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
       RAISE;
END;
```

I'm  not allowed to change the data type of `nreaderidn` and to modify the oracle function.
Is There a way to solve this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: The subtraction of dates in Oracle is number and then you are comparing them with date column. So the issue seems here `AND NDATETIME >= ((TO_DATE ('2020-01-27' || ' 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
  AND ndatetime <= ((TO_DATE ('2020-01-28' || ' 12:00:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 ` Can yo urun your query once without and cond and then see if it runs fine.

Comment: i think thats not the reason beacause when i put values on my where subquery it runs. so date subtraction is not the reason

Comment: Comment line by line and then tell as at what line of your query does the error fire. It is not like there is 100 lines.

Comment: already had . see above 1 ,2,3

Comment: sorry , i updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns a comma separated list of numbers, which needs to be split.
Try th

Eg:

```
SELECT 
   regexp_substr(GETREADERSBYFUNC('OUT', 'LOCKER'), '[^,]+', 1, level)  
FROM dual 
  connect by 
  regexp_substr(GETREADERSBYFUNC('OUT', 'LOCKER'), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
```

Your query would then look like:

```
SELECT L.NEVENTLOGIDN, LPAD (nuserid, 6, '0') nuserid, u.susername, 
  TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + ( (ndatetime) / (60 * 60 * 24)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
  date_time, l.nreaderidn, r.sname, 
  CASE WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT 
regexp_substr(GETREADERSBYFUNC('OUT', 'LOCKER'), '[^,]+', 1, level) FROM dual 
  connect by regexp_substr(GETREADERSBYFUNC('OUT', 'LOCKER'), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null ) THEN 'O' 
  WHEN l.nreaderidn IN (SELECT 
   regexp_substr(GETREADERSBYFUNC('IN', 'LOCKER'), '[^,]+', 1, level) FROM dual 
  connect by  regexp_substr(GETREADERSBYFUNC('IN', 'LOCKER'), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) THEN 'I' END logtype 
  FROM TB_EVENT_LOG l, TB_READER r, TB_USER u 
  WHERE 
  l.nreaderidn IN ( SELECT 
   regexp_substr(GETREADERSBYFUNC('LOCKER'), '[^,]+', 1, level)  FROM dual 
  connect by  regexp_substr(GETREADERSBYFUNC('LOCKER'), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) 
  AND NDATETIME >= ((TO_DATE ('2020-01-27' || ' 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
  AND ndatetime <= ((TO_DATE ('2020-01-28' || ' 12:00:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') ) - TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) * 24 * 60 * 60 
  AND l.nuserid = u.suserid 
  AND l.nreaderidn = r.nreaderidn 
  ORDER BY 2, 4
```

Comment: it trows me now  missing expression

Comment: What does your function return? Not sure why you have `devices` in your query above.

Comment: Can you run this individually and let me know the result?
`SELECT cast(GETREADERSBYFUNC('OUT', 'LOCKER') as int) FROM dual )`

Comment: error says SQL command not properly ended when trying to execute it

Comment: Just remove the last bracket !!:
`SELECT cast(GETREADERSBYFUNC('OUT', 'LOCKER') as int) FROM dual`

Comment: it still says invalid number when i try to run it without cast result looks like this '544381428','544381436','544381433','544381424','544381043'

Comment: result is each number on each row

Comment: Ok, can you plug this into your original query and try? See my updated answer.

Comment: as i plug it to my query it still says invalid number

Answer (score 0):

This will not give you an error:

```
SELECT * 
from TB_READER l
where cast(l.nreaderidn as varchar2(1024)) in (select GETREADERSBYDESC('LOCKER') devices FROM dual)
```

Just use the `cast` of the nreaderidn column.

But also be aware that you will search a varchar like for example '2' in the string(not an series of characters but one string) '1','2','3' so this will not retun any results.

Here is also a small example where you can see the errir being produced without a cast and solved when the cast is added:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=776ecd951aff56500938ac064b34788c